# how to update nested document using condition in mongodb with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb to store time series data in  following way

```
values: {
0: { 0: 999999, 1: 999999, …, 59: 1000000 },
1: { 0: 2000000, 1: 2000000, …, 59: 1000000 },
…,
58: { 0: 1600000, 1: 1200000, …, 59: 1100000 },
59: { 0: 1300000, 1: 1400000, …, 59: 1500000 }
}
```

But now i want to update specific range value 
FOR EXAMPLE. i want to set all values to 0  greater than **values.30.40** where **VALUES is the main node, 30 is MINUTES and 40 is SECOND**

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to change the inner Json to an array ?
That way, you can access and modify using indexes. 
It would also help when you do not have values at some indexes.

```
values: {
0:{[12,25,36,........,12]},
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: with above example still i can access particular element using dot operator. Like "values.30.40" but the problem is how can i specify condition to update all using $gt operator. eg. {"values":{$gt:"values.30.40"}